# pandas bar and line subplots with datetime and sharex

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, bar-chart, linechart

I want to make a figure with two subplots, that use sharex with datetime type.

- subplot 1: line plot from dataframe
- subplot 2: stacked bar plot from dataframe

For some reasons, and after lots of trials (inclduing using matplotlib.pyplot directly instead of pandas plot) I cannot make this mix work.

The use of sharex and datetime, seems not to be compatible with the stacked bar/line plot mix :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), periods = 5, freq = 'H')
y = np.random.randint(0,4,(5,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(index = x,data = y)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, sharex = True)
#fig.autofmt_xdate() 
df.sum(axis=1).plot(ax=axes[0])
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,ax=axes[1])
```

[image: Code outcome]

The xaxis of the line plot is correctly interpreted as a datetime type, however the bar plot is not, as shown in following example :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,1,1), periods = 5, freq = 'H')
y = np.random.randint(0,4,(5,3))

df = pd.DataFrame(index = x,data = y)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2)
#fig.autofmt_xdate()
df.sum(axis=1).plot(ax=axes[0])
df.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,ax=axes[1])

print('x-limits :')
print(axes[0].get_xlim())
print(axes[1].get_xlim())
```

xlim comes out with (438288.0, 438292.0) and (-0.5, 4.5).

I have then tried to trick the xticks and xlim of both subplots so that they are equivalent, but the figure stopped displaying anything meaningful (with sharex active or not):

```
axes[0].set_xticks(x)
axes[1].set_xticks(x)
axes[1].set_xticks(axes[1].get_xticks()*24)
axes[0].set_xlim([axes[0].get_xticks()[0],axes[0].get_xticks()[-1]])
axes[1].set_xlim([axes[0].get_xticks()[0],axes[0].get_xticks()[-1]])
print('x-ticks and xlim after modifications:')
print(axes[0].get_xticks())
print(axes[1].get_xticks()) 
print(axes[0].get_xlim())
print(axes[1].get_xlim())
```

Is the combination of **stacked bar plot** and **line plot**, with **sharex using datetime** possible at all ?

Comment: `df.plot(kind='bar')` actually  plots the data against `range(len(df))` and label the datetime accordingly.

Comment: To build on the previous comment, barplots are designed around categorical, not temporal axes